# What is wrong with this terraform template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I get an error message `│ An argument named "default_action" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "default_action"?` trying to apply this part of the tf template

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "HTTPS443" { 
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb.arn 
  port = "443" 
  protocol = "HTTPS"
   ssl_policy = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-0-2015-04" 
  certificate_arn = "${aws_acm_certificate.acm.arn}"  
  default_action { 
    type = "fixed-response"  
    fixed_response = { 
      content_type = "application/json" 
      message_body = "Nothing to see here"
       status_code  = "200" 
    }
   }
 }
```

However, based on the [terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener), this is how you define fixed response.

Am I missing something? My Terraform version is  v1.2.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `=` sign from the `fixed_response` [1] configuration block:

```
  default_action { 
    type = "fixed-response"  
    fixed_response { 
      content_type = "application/json" 
      message_body = "Nothing to see here"
       status_code  = "200" 
    }
   }
```

As a side note, make sure to replace `certificate_arn = "${aws_acm_certificate.acm.arn}"` with `certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.acm.arn` as if you do not remove it terraform will treat it as a string literal.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener#fixed-response-action

Comment: OMG. Thank you, @marko-e ! I didn't notice how i put the extra ```=``` there

Comment: BTW, the ```certificate_arn = "aws_acm_certificate.acm.arn``` should be ```certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.acm.arn``` . Thank you for this tip as well!

Comment: My bad, fixed that error, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @igalsc Acceptance of the answer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: accepted, should be visible now